# ReactDOM.render() query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started to build a demo project after learning React from some online tutorials.
Please consider the line of code below from a ReactComponent.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

This renders the React component ***Home*** at the target DOM element ***container***. All the tutorials online showed that this renders it in some index.html file. How does the code know, in which HTML(document) file to find the DOM element ***container***. Below is the screenshot of the error I am getting.

[image]

Below is my index.html which is the default one from scaffolding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show `index.html` file.

Comment: None of your elements in your `index.js` file have an `id` equal to `'container'`. Hence the error "Target container is not a DOM element".

Comment: One solution would be to change your `ReactDOM` statement to point to your `#root` `div` like so: `ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('root'))`

Comment: So does it mean that if I call `document.getElementById('container')` in any of component file, then it will refer to _index.html_? What if there is another index2.html?

Comment: either change the document.getElementById() from container to root as that's the only available div I can find there, or crate a new div called as container :)

Comment: I was confused with basics concepts. I am clear about everything from the comments collectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React, as all JavaScript, it's loaded into the file via an HTML file (i.e., the HTML file comes first). Your JavaScript is usually imported with a `<script>` tag. It's that HTML file currently open in the browser that it should look in.

So, you should have something like this for your HTML file, which you open in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="./src/Home.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
```

Opening that, assuming the JS path is correct, should work fine.

Comment: I have few more questions just to be sure.
1. So I will have to specify script name in every html file, right?
2. I just found that the tutorial I followed specifies compiled .js file path in the index.html. Do I need to do that?